# Sum counts for last three months of this dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following dataset and the date field on this is a string. How to write a query to sum counts for the last three months using this dataset:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this

```
SELECT TOP 3 YEAR, MONTH, SUM(Counts) as Total
FROM your_table
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH
ORDER BY  YEAR DESC, MONTH DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string date to date format.

```
select top 3 * from test order by convert(datetime,'01-'+date,6) desc
```

The above query will give you the data for last three months. Then you can do the `SUM()`

```
select sum(counts) as total from (
  select top 3 * from test order by convert(datetime,'01-'+dat,6) desc 
)a
```

[CHECK DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=652be75a2ddefcb454caecd68d48347a)

Answer (score 0):

According to @Phong answer you can get result the following way:

```
select sum(t.summary)
from (
 select top 3 sum(counts) summary
 from test
 group by y, m
 order by y desc, m desc
) t
```

OR you can use ROW_NUMBER() function to get the same result:

```
select sum(t.counts)
from (
 select mon, y, counts, 
    row_number() over(order by y desc, mon desc) RN
 from test
) t
where RN <= 3
```